# laravel - auth in laravel API

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

I have a question about token expire in laravel 5.1 .
when a user login to app in mobile, app send a token with expire time to mob.
mob use this for 1 hour. now after 1 hour how app get new token? we have to send user to login page and user have to login per 1 hour?
I can't know how can i refresh token before expire that.

Comment: you need to share the libraries you use, there is no default JWT library with Laravel 5.1

Comment: General note, you can extend your token library to the maximum you can achieve, and with every request from the user, the application authenticates, authorizes, renewes token, invalidates old token

Comment: @MinaAbadir thanks for comment. you mean I can't use from this package? https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth or this package : https://github.com/dingo/api/ . but i think this is good that I renew token per each request. do you think is that bad for server?